# mysql query result for a string words one by one with LIKE and LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql

as we know it, MySQL can get results by LIKE and LIMIT, but my problem is how we can search DB for some words of a string one by one and show result without duplication?

my means is for example when user make search for "a book for php and mysql" we send query in For loop, word to word to DB by:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE %i% LIMIT 5
```

but this code just show duplicated result, indeed for each word it shows 5 results then for another word another 5 result and... i need to search db for words one by one, but at last show just 5 match results without duplication! sorry for my poor english:)

Comment: Can you give an example of some data and your expected result set for querying that data?

Comment: please explain your question through an example.

Comment: You could just use UNION between each query. This would remove the duplicates.

Comment: of course, for example user search "what is php" then we send query to DB in a For loop for each word, in loop 1: SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE %what% LIMIT 5; in loop 2: SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE %is% LIMIT 5; and in loop 3: SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE %php% LIMIT 5; now it will show 15 result (each loop 5 result), but i need 5 unique result of 15 at last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been reading the comments and your question, and I think that you need a bit of PHP to prepare your MySql statement, and a Mysql Query to fetch matching results limited to the first 5 without repeated items?

*If so!!*

**PHP**

```
<?php
  $searchFieldData = $_POST['search'];
  $searchArr = explode(" ", $searchFieldData);

  $sqlWhere = '';
  $count = count($searchArr);
  foreach ($searchArr as $or) {
    $sqlWhere.= " title LIKE '%".$or."%' ";
    if ($count>1) $sqlWhere.= " OR ";
    $count--;
  }

  $query = "SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM table WHERE ".$sqlWhere." LIMIT 5";
?>
```

**The above code would return for the search term:** "super hyper query crawler"

*SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%super%' OR title LIKE '%hyper%' OR title LIKE '%query%' OR title LIKE '%crawler%' LIMIT 5*

---

**NOW FOR THE MYSQL MAGIC**

If you don't want any repeated results, just use: *GROUP BY 'title'*

and your final query would be:

```
$query = "SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM table WHERE ".$sqlWhere." GROUP BY 'title' LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: @Mark Byers, Mark Byers, took me a while to test this, and after posting there was your answer... you may consider this an improvement, not a duplicate :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM table
WHERE title LIKE '%a%' OR title LIKE '%b%' OR title LIKE '%c%'
LIMIT 5
```

Notes:

- Using `LIKE '%xxx%'` is slow for large data sets. Consider using an indexed full text search instead.
- Searching for words like 'a' or 'the' will likely give lots of useless matches. Consider using a stop word list or some other approach to improve the relevance of the matches.

Comment: i know this! but what i do if words was more than 3 or less than it?! so as you can see it's not a dynamic way!

Comment: @vahid: You could build the query dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to achieve this only by MySQL? I show one with **PHP**:

```
$result = array();
$excludeIds = array(); //store recored id already got
$words = explode(" ", $_POST['input']);
foreach($words as $word) {

  //if there is no 'id' column, use another one instead
  $condForNoDup = ($excludeIds) ?
    "AND id NOT IN (".implode(',', $excludeIds).")" : "";

  $word = '%'.mysql_real_escape_string($word).'%';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM table
          WHERE title LIKE '{$word}' {$condForNoDup}
          LIMIT 5";

  //executeQuery() returns array which has 'id' as key
  if($_result = executeQuery($sql)) {
    $excludeIds = array_merge($excludeIds, array_keys($result));
    $result = array_merge($result, $_result);
  }
}
print_r($result);
```

Awkward...I also want to know smart answer only with MySQL:)